# Moderator tools deleted posts incomplete?

Tags: bug, deleted-answers

The moderator tools contain information [recently deleted posts](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days). When I look there, [this post](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/898/130) is not listed. Why not?

Comment: I can't see the post, but e.g. self-deleted posts are intentionally not listed there.

Comment: The deletion notice says "Deleted by Community ♦". It also says "Locked by Community ♦".

Answer (score 1):

It appears that posts where the owner has been deleted do not appear in this list. [As Mad Scientist suggests](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248/moderator-tools-deleted-posts-incomplete/258#comment371_248), this is due to the self-delete check - although I'm not sure it's intentional; throwing a null into a boolean expression tends to produce odd results in SQL.